# JS Unit Testing with <input type='file' />

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine and have run into a scenario which requires me to interact with:

```
<input type='file'/>
```

Most of my interaction lies within the 'onChange' event. This app does some pre-processing of a CSV file before I upload to the server.

I'm able to mock / stub out most things (file size, file extension, headers, etc.), however I'd love to be able to actually stub out an actual file and run a test against that.  Is this possible / makes sense for js unit testing? I realize that this can be done within integration testing (cucumber / selenium tests) however if I could do it within jasmine, that would give me a bit more piece of mind.